# How to test user session within integration test in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd

I am new to BDD and I have this controller that requires a user session how can I test that in RSpec? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly set the required key in the `session` variable which is used for verifying that the user session is set. From the [RSpec documentation](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html) you can access the session variable using `session` like in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use some Authentication Plugin/Gem, such as Devise, Restful_Authentication or Authlogic?

Normally they come with certain TestHelper-Methods, that allow you to do kind of an authentication while testing.

Comment: No due to some custom requirements.

Answer (score -6):

Don't. Integration testing is a job for Cucumber, not RSpec.

Comment: FALSE! Integration testing has absolutely nothing to do with the tool you use. (Ever hear of RSpec Scenarios?). Integration testing is just black box testing. PERIOD!.

Comment: @Snuggs FALSE yourself! :) Certain tools work better for integration testing than others; that's a fact. Of course I've heard of RSpec scenarios. They exist, but are a poor tool for this type of testing. Cucumber works at the proper level of abstraction for this type of testing, since it describes user actions in user terms. RSpec does not—it uses programmer terms (unless you reimplement an equivalent to Cucumber on top of it—and then you might as well just use Cucumber). Using the right tool for the job is important. I stand by my original statement.

Comment: Very true. That is if "stake holders" actually sat with the developers to write cucumber specs.  That RARELY happens.  Tell the truth. Why do you think Cucumber has lost so much steam as of late. At the end of the day it winds up being a developer who has a pipe dream of a stake holder playing with them in their sandbox.  It's hard enough to get a human to speak proper english let alone write a cucumber spec. Here's what I've learned. Doesn't matter your testing methodology. Just test! CYA (Cover Your (own) A$$)

Comment: @Snuggs It's not only the stakeholders. There is value *for the developer* in describing UI in English, not Ruby. The stakeholder benefit is secondary to the clarity that the *developer* gets from thinking of the UI in user terms, not programmer terms. And while some testing is better than no testing, a good testing methodology is better than a bad one. So I'm basically disagreeing with everything you said here. :)

Comment: @Snuggs Also, if I ever have a question about how a feature should operate, I could show a Cucumber story to a client for verification. That's not a major benefit, though, in comparison to the fact that I benefit from seeing a high-level description of the UI I'm building, *described from the user's point of view*.

Comment: How many times have you honestly done that in the past week? I've worked with startups of less than a handful of people to my current project which is the highest grossing company in NYC. Clients still like to clickity clackaround the browser. People don't like to write and they REALLY don't like to read. When you throw a cucumber spec in front of a client it's because YOU did that. They never ask for it. Just because you do something doesn't mean your client likes it. That's a developer mentality not a business mentality. There's a difference. #WhyWriteCukesWhenYouHavePivotalTracker

Comment: @Snuggs As I said, I don't show Cucumber stories to my client often (if ever). I find value in Cucumber stories for *the developer*. Read my previous posts. Why write Cucumber stories when you have Tracker? Simple: because they're executable automated tests that describe the app functionality in UI terms, not programmer terms. If you think Tracker can take the place of Cucumber, then you don't understand how to use Cucumber effectively.